# CSV export in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, csv, playframework-2.0

```
 String outputFile = "users.csv";
 outputFile = new String(outputFile.getBytes("Windows-31J"), "ISO8859_1");
 response().setContentType("application/octet-stream;charset=Windows-31J");
 response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
 filename=\"" + outputFile + "\"");
```

i also write in my code like that.
but, output (CSV excel) come with the data of HTML code.
example; 
so. if you have CSV export sample source code.,plz can you share me ??
(I am from Myanmar.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may get you started. Look for JavaCSV (http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(stream, ',', Charset.forName(UTF8));
// add records
csv.close();
return ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()));
```